# Google maps geocode API not working when using authentication

Tags: php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api

I've set up a small PHP script that verifies user submitted address information with google's geocode API over CURL.

```
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#GeocodingRequests
```

It all works fine using the normal quota you get daily per IP. However whenever I try to authenticate using my API key I get a REQUEST_DENIED response.

Successful response

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=Agadir
```

Request denied

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=Agadir&key={my_api_key}
```

I've set up my project to allow access on that service (Google Maps API v3), and I'm certainly nowhere near the daily quota. I'm also 100% sure my API key is correct.

Does anyone know if the API keys take some time to propagate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `base64_decode()` the API key, then sign the URL. [Working code from Google](http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/urlsigning/UrlSigner.php-source).

Comment: This page has links to code samples for a number of other languages in addition to PHP: http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/urlsigning/index.html

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the key is not needed for geocoding requests. I just opened this link: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=Agadir in my browser and got valid JSON. No key specified. What you should try is to use any of free CGI proxies maybe or another machine and try to go to this url with your browser first.

Comment: Sure I can get a response using the allowed quota, but I'm sure I'll eventually exceed this so I want it work with authentication.

Comment: sorry, my bad, I re-read your post and see you mentioned that without the key it works fine. But I just opened their doc and in Russian version there is a warning that API key is no longer needed. Instead you need to sign every URL making requests with crypto key but this is Premier service. I can't find any confirmation in the English version of their doc, but here is what I found about the issue: http://blog.programmableweb.com/2010/03/10/google-says-goodbye-to-api-keys-with-new-geocoding-api/

Comment: see above: http://blog.programmableweb.com/2010/03/10/google-says-goodbye-to-api-keys-with-new-geocoding-api/ - this is all I can find at the moment and this is not an official doc. If you'd like to see , you can open Russian doc here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/?hl=ru-RU and use google translate it

Answer (score 0):

Try using https instead of http at your request denied, as Google Api need requests over SSL.